# Simple MPI program hangs

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, mpi

I'm trying to use mpi to calculate every number that fulfilles some certain requirement by brute force trying. It runs fine when I only run one process, but when I try and run multiple processes, it never ends. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>


using std::cout, std::endl;

#define SIZE 32

/** EXTRACT_BIT is a macro that extracts the ith bit of number n.
 *
 * parameters: n, a number;
 *             i, the position of the bit we want to know.
 *
 * return: 1 if 'i'th bit of 'n' is 1; 0 otherwise
 */
#define EXTRACT_BIT(n, i) ((n & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0)

int checkCircuit(int id, bool *v)
{
  if ( ( (v[0] || v[1]) && (!v[1] || !v[3]) && (v[2] || v[3])
      && (!v[3] || !v[4]) && (v[4] || !v[5])
      && (v[5] || !v[6]) && (v[5] || v[6])
      && (v[6] || !v[15]) && (v[7] || !v[8])
      && (!v[7] || !v[13]) && (v[8] || v[9])
      && (v[8] || !v[9]) && (!v[9] || !v[10])
      && (v[9] || v[11]) && (v[10] || v[11])
      && (v[12] || v[13]) && (v[13] || !v[14])
      && (v[14] || v[15]) )
      &&
         ( (v[16] || v[17]) && (!v[17] || !v[19]) && (v[18] || v[19])
      && (!v[19] || !v[20]) && (v[20] || !v[21])
      && (v[21] || !v[22]) && (v[21] || v[22])
      && (v[22] || !v[31]) && (v[23] || !v[24])
      && (!v[23] || !v[29]) && (v[24] || v[25])
      && (v[24] || !v[25]) && (!v[25] || !v[26])
      && (v[25] || v[27]) && (v[26] || v[27])
      && (v[28] || v[29]) && (v[29] || !v[30])
      && (v[30] || v[31]) ) )
  {
     std::printf("%d) %d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d \n", id,
            v[31], v[30], v[29], v[28], v[27], v[26], v[25], v[24], v[23], v[22],
            v[21], v[20], v[19], v[18], v[17], v[16], v[15], v[14], v[13], v[12],
            v[11], v[10], v[9], v[8], v[7], v[6], v[5], v[4], v[3], v[2], v[1], v[0]);
     fflush(stdout);
     return 1;
  } else {
     return 0;
  }}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int numProcesses, id;
   unsigned int i, combination;
   int count = 0;
   int globalCount = 0; // The variable to store the global count
   bool *v = new bool[SIZE];

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcesses);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);   

   cout << endl << "Process " << id << " is checking the circuit..." << endl;

   double startTime = MPI_Wtime();

   for (combination = id; combination < UINT_MAX; combination += numProcesses)
   {
      for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
         v[i] = EXTRACT_BIT(combination, i);

      count += checkCircuit(id, v);
   }

   MPI_Reduce(&count, &globalCount, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   double endTime = MPI_Wtime();
   double totalTime = endTime - startTime;

   double totalElapsedTime;
   MPI_Reduce(&totalTime, &totalElapsedTime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   if (id == 0)
   {
      cout << "Total time: " << totalElapsedTime << " seconds." << endl;
      cout << "A total of " << globalCount << " solutions were found." << endl << endl;
   }

   MPI_Finalize();

   delete[] v;

   return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Process 1 is checking the circuit...

Process 2 is checking the circuit...

Process 3 is checking the circuit...

Process 0 is checking the circuit...
2) 10011001111101011001100111110110
2) 10011001111101011001101111110110
2) 10011001111101011001110111110110
2) 10011001111101101001100111110110
2) 10011001111101101001101111110110
2) 10011001111101101001110111110110
2) 10011001111101111001100111110110
2) 10011001111101111001101111110110
2) 10011001111101111001110111110110
1) 10011001111101011001100111110101
1) 10011001111101011001101111110101
1) 10011001111101011001110111110101
1) 10011001111101101001100111110101
1) 10011001111101101001101111110101
1) 10011001111101101001110111110101
1) 10011001111101111001100111110101
1) 10011001111101111001101111110101
1) 10011001111101111001110111110101
3) 10011001111101011001100111110111
3) 10011001111101011001101111110111
3) 10011001111101011001110111110111
3) 10011001111101101001100111110111
3) 10011001111101101001101111110111
3) 10011001111101101001110111110111
3) 10011001111101111001100111110111
3) 10011001111101111001101111110111
3) 10011001111101111001110111110111
etcetera etcetera.
```

at some point it gets stuck in process 1 and 2 and I can't wrap my head around it. Can anyone help?

Comment: ```combination < UINT_MAX; combination += numProcesses``` This could give you problems with overflow/wrap-around when an unsigned int gets close to UINT_MAX and numProcesses is not 1.

Comment: i now have "combination < UINT_MAX - numProcesses" and it works, thank you!